# Рукопашный бой

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы понять слово "рукопашный". С первым корнем сложностей нет, но вот второй? От слова "пахать"? Но какое отношение пашня имеет к драке?
Буду благодарен за правильную версию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна из версий происхождения слова "пахать" - взрыхлять землю такова: пахать от пахати-мести, махать, обметать, отваливать землю,вздувать пыль, веять(звукоподражание пых-пыхать). От него - пахнУть(махнуть), запахнУть(полы одежды), опахало.

Рукопашная -от прил. рукопашный = наречие рукопашь(сохранилось в диалектах)+ -ьн-.

Рукопашь от руко+пашь(как роскошь)х//ш от пахать = махать В диалектах известны слова опахати(обмахнуть),опашь(хвост животного),наопашь(внакидку). Рукопашная схватка в просторечии махалово

Answer (score 3):

Сразу вспоминаются слова *опахало* и *опахивать*.

> **Опахивать**
> опахать , опахнуть кого, обдувать, обвевать,
> обмахивать; что, обметать. Ветер опахивает
> прохладой. **Опахни меня рукою**, у тебя рука
> легка, сымает головную боль. В Индии слуги
> весь день опахивают господ своих опахалами.
> Опахни-ка блюдо, сгони мух, да накрой его.
> Опахни пыль. Опахни пол, подмети; в арх.
> олон. вместо мести всегда говорится пахать, а
> вместо пахать говорится орать, как на Украине.
> Встарь, молодых опахивали соболями.
> (Словарь Даля)

Из Нацкорпуса :

> А. Ф. Писемский. Тысяча душ (1858)
> Ночь была осенняя, темная, хоть глаз, как говорится, выколи; порывистый **ветер опахивал холодными волнами** и воймя завывал где-то в соседней трубе.
> Л. А. Кассиль. Кондуит и Швамбрания (1928-1931)
> На переднем возу высоко вверху, как раджа на слоне, сидела Аннушка. **Ее опахивал лист пальмы.** Аннушка держала чучело филина.

Answer (score 1):

пахать здесь в значении-размахивать...в итоге -Махать руками